# u-boot from Micro SD on A13 board

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

I am trying to restore an Allwinner A13 based OEM board to working condition, because the original SD card died and there is currently no way to get an original backup image.
Only thing I have so far is the linux rootfs and a partition table it wants to use (The original sizes and filesystems are too unknown to me, so I used what i deemed purposeful).
I have created the partition table, put the rootfs into its partition and set up the toolchain to compile the u-boot + spl.

The board itself only has one Micro SD slot, and this card contains the u-boot + SPL on its first megabyte after the partition table.

The spl and u-boot layout I use:

```
sector  (512b)  start   size    usage
---------------------------------------
0-15    (16)    0kb     8kb     MBR+GPT
16-79   (64)    8kb     32kb    SPL
80-2047 (1968)  40kb    984kb   u-boot
2048    (----)  1024kb  (----)  partitions
```

The partition table:

```
1 MBR   512MB FAT   "mmcblk0p1"  drive for recovery firmware dumps
2 MBR   512MB FAT   "mmcblk0p2"  boot volume. perhaps for u-boot environment
3 MBR                            GPT Container
4 GPT                           
5 GPT                           
6 GPT   2048MB ext2 "mmcblk0p6"  rootfs
7 GPT   4096MB ext2 "mmcblk0p7"  file system for user data
8 GPT   1024MB ext2 "mmcblk0p8"  squash image and/or backup are stored here
```

The rootfs partition contains a folder named `boot` with these files inside, so I assume the SPL / u-boot eventually wants to boot from there:

```
/boot/script.bin          32KB
/boot/devicetree.dtb      38KB
/boot/uImage            5200KB
```

The SPL dies with the following error message on the serial (it doesn't even find the u-boot, the result is the same with only the SPL part dd-ed on the card):

```
U-Boot SPL 2020.07-rc4-STT-LMT-00022-gbe79009f3b (Jun 12 2020 - 23:40:45 +0000)
DRAM: 256 MiB
CPU: 1008000000Hz, AXI/AHB/APB: 3/2/2
Trying to boot from MMC2
MMC Device 1 not found
spl: could not find mmc device 1. error: -19
SPL: failed to boot from all boot devices
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

How can I successfully have this boot the os on the rootfs?

Comment: Which defconfig did you use to build U-Boot? Typically the sunxi 32bit boards use "sudo dd conv=fsync,notrunc if=u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin of=/dev/sdx bs=8k seek=1" to copy U-Boot to the SD card. Replace /dev/sdx with the relevant device. http://www.orangepi.org/Docs/Settingup.html gives you and idea how to use script.bin.

Comment: defconfig was olinuxino a13, for dd flashing I used `dd if=u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin of=/dev/sdd bs=1024 seek=8` - should be the same. The problem seems though that the spl does not even come as far as to load the script.bin.

Comment: The board tries to boot from MMC2 according to the log. But CONFIG_MMC_SUNXI_SLOT_EXTRA is not set by default for A13-OLinuXino_defconfig. Maybe setting this parameter 1, 2, or 3 helps.